# Cómo mantener sesion activa en aplicaciones android

Tags: android

hola buenas estoy desarrollando una aplicación en android studio y necesito hacer que una vez que el usuario haya iniciado sesión esta se mantenga activa, es decir que al momento de cerrar la aplicación o volver atrás el usuario no tenga que iniciar sesión nuevamente.

Por lo que he buscado y leído esto se puede hacer utilizando SharedPreferences pero no es recomendado si se quiere guardar contraseñas, también he leído que se puede utilizar tokens pero desconozco como funcionan estos.

¿Cuál seria la manera correcta de hacer esto?

cabe mencionar que utilizo un hosting para almacenar los datos del usuario

Comment: yo pensaria en almacenar en la base de datos para el uid del dispositvo una bandera de sesion iniciada y cuando se entre a la app consultar al servidor si ese uid device tiene la sesion abierta, si es asi que lo deje pasar. pienso yo que deberia ser asi.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aqui te dejo un [mcve]